# How to create feed using admin account without submit app - Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to publish a feed. I receive an error

`The permission(s) manage_pages,publish_pages are not available. It could because either they are deprecated or need to be approved by App Review.`

After I take a look at their example for [app review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples), I see this.

[image]

In my understanding, I think this mean I do not need for a app review if I use admin user access token. Correct me if I am wrong.

As I am the only one who will publish feed on my page, I try to set the access token to my admin account access token. But, I receive another error

`(#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself.`

Is that mean the only way I can do is to submit app review?

Comment: This is outdated info. You will need to submit your app for review, otherwise you will not be able to grant all necessary permissions to your app once it is in live mode, even if you use it with a user that has a role in the app. (And you need to be in live mode, otherwise normal users will not get to see the posts you create via this app in the first place.)

Comment: Cool. Thank you.